# What is the meaning of attr("d", path)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, attr

I tried to find about 'd' in Official site...
Maybe,, it's not related to D3.... 
 related more to javascript, css, svg, html....

What is the meaning of    attr("d", path) ?

```
.....................
var areas = group.append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");
```

Is it different with  d in d3?

```
.style({
    'font-size':'18px',
    'padding':'6px',
    'margin':'4px',
    'list-style':'none',
    'background':function(d){
      return d.background;
    },
    'color':function(d){
      return d.color;
    },
    'width':function(d){
      return d.width+'%';
    }
  });
```

Comment: `d` in `attr`define the path. where as `d` in function is data

Comment: In SVG the `d` attribute defines the path. Please read about the [SVG d attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d)

Comment: Thank you for answer.....well......What is the meaning of 'path' in SVG... Is it something like 'coordinate' for making a figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `d` attribute of a `svg` element defines the shape of the `svg` in *SVG Path Mini-Language*.
The reference for this language can be found on the following links.

> **SVG Path Example**
>
> The shape of an SVG Path element is defined by one attribute: d.
>
> This attribute, d, contains a series of commands and parameters in the
>   SVG Path Mini-Language.
>
> These commands and parameters are a sequential set of instructions for
>   how to "move the pen over the paper".

Ref:[Dashing D3js & SVG Paths](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js)

and MDN:

> The d attribute defines a path to be drawn.
>
> A path definition is a list of path commands where each command is
>   composed of a command letter and numbers that represent the command
>   parameters. The commands are detailed below.

Ref: [d - SVG: Scalable Vector Graphics | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d)
Path Commands: [SVG Path Commands | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#Path_commands)

Comment: Thank you for answer.....well..........What is the meaning of 'path' in SVG......i'm not good English speaker and catcher for getting the full  meaning of a word...... Is it something like 'coordinate' for making a figure?

Comment: yes. it is like a list of mathematical `f(x)` plotting a figure on a coordinate graph in SVG. checkout the MDN link in the answer for complete details.